# Fitted values of tsoutliers from R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, outliers

I am trying to identify outliers from a simple time series (`ts1`; see below) and subsequently fit an ARIMA model on the adjusted ts (w/o the outliers). Appologies, if the questions below are beginner's questions.

I have a question concerning the fitted values for the tsoutliers package in R. 
I thought that the package identifies outliers iteratively, thereby fitting an ARIMA model. I am not not sure now, how to interpret the output of [?tso](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsoutliers/versions/0.6-6/topics/tso) `$fit$fitted`.

What I do:

```
tt_out <- tso(ts, types=c("AO"))
plot(tt_out)
```

[image]

```
  plot(tt_out$fit$fitted)
```

[image]

So from these two plots, I can tell that one outlier was correctly identified (at t=172), however, the fitted values still incorporate the outlier. So what are they for?
If I want to run ARIMA without the outliers do I need to do this: 
Replace the outlier by the adjusted value (yhat) and then run ARIMA from the package `forecast`. However, I thought the goal was to automatically identify  and to fit the model directly.

Why is the output of `tso` fit including the outliers? Do I need to use `tso` to identify the outliers, and then run ARIMA seperately?

```
ts1 <- as.ts(c(12,108,72,84,72,108,24,72,60,60,84,36,12,0,24,12,60,48,60,12,12,60,24,12,48,0,36,0,36,24,60,48,36,12,12,12,60,24,84,24,36,48,24,72,12,36,36,36,24,60,48,108,24,48,12,156,84,108,84,108,108,132,96,108,96,60,144,132,144,96,216,252,192,168,252,216,324,420,420,468,528,444,468,516,468,516,456,528,420,684,480,420,600,504,312,420,480,384,528,528,504,540,420,612,348,468,444,444,456,480,528,372,444,372,384,384,444,432,504,492,432,348,408,396,444,408,372,456,372,384,324,480,636,432,456,468,588,336,420,456,384,312,432,360,336,516,444,468,396,360,264,240,252,252,312,372,324,348,396,432,432,384,444,288,384,468,348,348,252,180,300,48,516,444,336,504,300,360,492,492,336,384,372,492,492,456,396,372,396,504,420,468,492,348,396,420,516,552,312,540,528,528,552,468,336,492,444,492,312,564,420,396,588,408,444,432,444,396,396,348,528,504,348,528,408,408,540,360,348,360,300,360,312,276,312,240,324,228,276,180,288,192,240,288,264,288,348,240,384,492,288,312,252,240,216,264,300,216,372,240,252,240,432,348,216,228,336,228,204,144,192,240,168,96,312,312,264,180,204,240,156,156,72,132,144,144,156,84))
```

Comment: The fitted values are the original series minus the residuals of the fitted model. You can get the fitted series without the outlier effects as follows:
`x1 = ts - residuals(tt_out$fit) - tt_out$effects` or `x2 = tt_out$yadj - residuals(tt_out$fit)`, `all.equal(x1, x2)`.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it. A follow-up question, why would we be interested in the fitted series with the outlier (if we don't do any prediction afterwards)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in the [variance](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/for.3980070102/abstract) in the data beginning around period 60. Tsay argued in his paper that if you don't identify variance change then you can't find the outliers.  TSO likely suffered from that pitfall and didn't continue to detect more outliers. It's clearly visible in the data that the variance had a change.

[image]

The AR 2 was identified first ,for this model, and then the search for outliers after and then the [WLS](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm) identified and applied due to the change in variance.

The TSO package is catching only one outlier (at period 173) when there are many others being ignored.

An AR 2 with lag of 1 and 2 with these outliers plus drift might be a good model to use.

Y(T) =  299.59
       +[X1(T)][(-  317.32    )]                        :PULSE           172   I~P00172sfd
       +[X2(T)][(+  223.87    )]                        :PULSE           133   I~P00133sfd
       +[X3(T)][(+  218.32    )]                        :PULSE            90   I~P00090sfd
       +[X4(T)][(-  217.80    )]                        :PULSE           199   I~P00199sfd
       +[X5(T)][(-  201.40    )]                        :PULSE            95   I~P00095sfd
       +[X6(T)][(+  195.75    )]                        :PULSE           250   I~P00250sfd
       +[X7(T)][(+  177.69    )]                        :PULSE           263   I~P00263sfd
       +[X8(T)][(+  168.82    )]                        :PULSE           173   I~P00173sfd
       +[X9(T)][(+  166.28    )]                        :PULSE           213   I~P00213sfd
       +[X10(T)[(-  167.90    )]                        :PULSE           274   I~P00274sfd
       +[X11(T)[(+  162.32    )]                        :PULSE           137   I~P00137sfd
       +[X12(T)[(+  160.08    )]                        :PULSE           227   I~P00227sfd
       +[X13(T)[(-  155.67    )]                        :PULSE           205   I~P00205sfd
       +[X14(T)[(-  152.18    )]                        :PULSE           209   I~P00209sfd
       +[X15(T)[(+  148.71    )]                        :PULSE           104   I~P00104sfd
       +[X16(T)[(-  149.40    )]                        :PULSE           170   I~P00170sfd
       +[X17(T)[(+  137.90    )]                        :PULSE           221   I~P00221sfd
      +     [(1-  .474B** 1-  .482B** 2)]**-1  [A(T)]   sfd

[image: Actual and Cleansed]

[image: Tsay Variance Test]

[image: Residuals]

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. The reason why not more outliers are detected is the default value of cval and that I am only interested in additive outliers (AO). Setting a lower cval will result in many more outliers identified. However, I am interested if it makes sense to remove outliers with tso() and then use the adjusted values to fit an ARIMA and why the fitted values in tso() include the outliers.

Comment: The 17 listed above are all AO.  The variance change isn't an "outlier".  It's not about "removing" outliers them, but rather adding them in.  You add them in by creating a dummy variables (ie 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 etc.).